# Как программой Python управлять внешним источником питания от ПК

Tags: python, com-порт

Почему блок питания от ПК?

- стандартный
- мощный
- несколько напряжений
- возможна доработка для повышения напряжения с целью программного 
  заряда автомобильных аккумуляторов при исследовании режимов заряда.
- есть линия управления на постоянном токе.
- компьютер может выдать любую стабильную частоту, что расширяет возможности комплекта состоящего из компьютера и внешнего источника питания ПК.

В домашних условиях, из резонансных систем, это качели, и стабильная частота на выходе источника питания позволит осуществить управляемый привод.

Проблемы и варианты решения аппаратной части:

Параллельный порт слабо защищен, и может сжечь всю машину. Годится для подключения опробованных устройств с предварительным обесточиванием. Для исследований применять нежелательно.

Пищалка динамика достаточно мощная и через ферритовое кольцо может включить два тиристора. После тиристоров нужна фильтрация при включении на трансформатор.

Вопрос сужается:

Как нестандартного применить COM порт для целей управления?

Comment: За что минусуете-то?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что постановка задачи совершенно не ясна.

Answer (score 3):

Нестандартное применение COM порта хорошо описано в rsapi.dll для VBA.
Вопрос подключения rsapi.dll к Python пока без ответа.

Python могу рекомендовать устанавливать в комплекте с научными пакетами.

Python(x,y)-2.7.10.0.exe 847530296 байт, там есть все и если поставить птичку, и PySerial.

Есть еще  Anaconda-2.3.0-Windows-x86.exe 290903240 байт.

COM порт позволяет использовать три выхода +/- 10 вольт 1 миллиампер с полной защитой от статики и замыканий.
Есть также три входа.

Если предполагается применение для измерений тестера, например UT60D, эти линии заняты, и остается линия выхода (3 контакт).

Если передавать в порт код "0" на выходе будут только стоп импульсы.
Кстати VBA позволяет передавать только "1", "0" блокируется.
В Python есть оператор блокировки выхода, который на любое время дает чистое напряжение, которым и будем включать источник питания.

Еще понабиться транзистор n-p-n, любой, лучше с большими выводами, чтобы было удобно прикручивать провода. Коллектор подключаем  на известный из форумов зеленый провод, эмиттер на корпус, черный провод. Базу через резистор от 1 ком до 20 ком на выход COM порта. Корпус внешнего ПК соединить с корпусом компьютера.

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('COM1', 2400, dsrdtr = 0,timeout =     0,bytesize=7)

   for cik in range (12):
   ser.sendBreak (cik/30.0+0.1)
   time.sleep(0.5)

ser.close ()
```

Нагружаем источник автомобильной лампочкой. При работе программы наблюдаем импульсы напряжения разной длительности.

Фотография и видео качелей, как объекта управления:
https://youtu.be/KJCnzE5icZ8
[image: Фотография качелей]